# Cannot display default value in Angular JS Select control when coming from a different service than data in the list

Tags: angularjs

I´ve been looking for other questions about Select using Angular but I think they all talk about populating hardcoded data into the select or maybe just from one service. In my case I want to populate data coming from one service, but choose the default option that has been retrieved from another service.

In this case, every Reservation contains a field with a Customer, so I want to display all customers names in the select (customers.shortName), but the default value comes from the reservation (reservation.customerName). Controller:

```
$scope.reservation = ReservationFactory.show({id: $routeParams.id}); 
$scope.customers= CustomersFactory.query();
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="reservation.customerName" ng-options="x.shortName for x in customers" required class="form-control" id="customerName" placeholder="customer name"><select/>
```

The data is populated correctly, but I can´t find a way of showing the default data (reservation.customerName). I have also made it work hardcoding the list of customers into the controller or setting for instance the first value of the list as default, but when calling 2 services it doesn´t work. I think it makes sense because I´m calling 2 asynchronous services, so maybe I should do something to refresh the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="reservation.customerName">
    <option ng-repeat="x in customers" value="{{x.shortName}}">{{x.shortName}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Almost! In this case the default value appears correctly but it is displayed twice in the list. Anycase this solution shows that both sources of data are available, so it makes my wonder what it is wrong with my solution. Many thanks!!!

Comment: That is a problem with the data my friend. You say and I quote, _"every Reservation contains a field with a Customer, so I want to display all customers names in the select (customers.shortName), but the default value comes from the reservation (reservation.customerName)"_. So the customer witha reservation is also in the entire customer. list. You might want to remove that from the customer list.

Comment: I removed the first option line from your answer and now it is not duplicated. Thanks!

Comment: Although I´m still wondering why your solution works and not mine... They are supposed to be the same, right?

Comment: I will need the data for that. But can you try this?
`<select ng-model="x.shortName" ng-options="x as x.shortName for x in customers" required class="form-control" id="customerName" placeholder="customer name"><select/>`

Answer (score 0):

if the data are asynchronous  just wrap in a ng-if the select in order to wait the variables do be populated

```
<select ng-if="reservation && customers" ng-model="reservation.customerName" 
 ng-options="x.shortName for x in customers" 
 required class="form-control" id="customerName" placeholder="customer name">
<select/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Trying sisyphus solution it proves both data are available, so my problem has to do strictly with the use of the select control and how to show the default data.